# MySQL SELECT Probability like-dislike system

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, probability

I'm creating a YouTube comment style (like-dislike) PHP app for my blogging website.

I want the comments to be arranged randomly; however, I want chances to increase based on the ratio of likes to dislikes. For example:

A comment with 5 likes and 1 dislike will have a higher chance of being selected than a comment with 4 likes and 2 dislikes since 5/1 is higher than 4/2. Therefore, the like-dislike ratio is directly proportional to the chance of being displayed in the comments section.

I'm using PHP and MySQL. I need help with creating some sort of algorithm for this. I know It's quite challenging, but if you can think of some sort of MySQL query for this, that would be great. :D

Comment: http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me assume that you have a table of comments with columns like `NumLikes` and `NumDislikes`.

One simple approach that you can take is to order the rows by the ratio (or by the probability of like descending) and be biased in choosing a lower row than a higher row.

The following randomly chooses a row and then randomly chooses a row with a better ratio than that row.  This biases the selection process toward the better rows:

```
select *
from comments c cross join
     (select c.*
      from comments c
      order by rand() desc
      limit 1
     ) threshhold
where c.likes / (c.likes + c.dislikes) >= threshold.likes / (threshold.likes + threshold.dislikes)
order by rand()
limit 1
```

There are more complicated techniques.  Because MySQL does not support window/analytic functions, they are most easily implemented with temporary tables and multiple queries.  This approach, however, only requires a single query and no temporary tables.

Comment: How can I do this with: http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html
I want to use the Wilson formula so it's more accurate. Thank you :D

Comment: @MicoAbrina: Scroll to the bottom of the article. There's an example SQL query.

Comment: @MicoAbrina . . . My usual method is to calculate the ratio and then subtract one standard error using the "square root of pq/n" formula.  That is, take a pessimistic statistical estimate of the ratio.  In your case, I'm guessing the tail is very long due to posts that have only one like or dislike.  When you have a long tail, start with the simplest approach and only refine it if necessary.

Comment: Yup! I noticed the SQL query in evanmiller.org. :D However, how do I mix that up with the bias system of your code?

Comment: @MicoAbrina . . . Instead of the ratio, you would use the lower bound estimate in *both* cases (which affects both sides of the `where` clause).  I tend to go for a one-standard error difference.  The article is proposing a 95% confidence lower bound.  I can't strongly defend one against the other, because they are both heuristic.

Comment: Thanks! You've been a great help! What do you think is more effective? The code you've given me or the code in evanmiller.org. I wanted to create a system of random probability sorting because I wanted all comments to have chances of being seen. The only thing I'm afraid of is that the snippet in evanmiller.org will not give chances to people with less likes/dislikes.

Comment: @MicoAbrina . . . This is all an approximation, as such I'd go with the simpler version (this solution).  The right solution would be to take all the lower bounds, and than randomly pick a value from them.  That requires either analytic functions or a temporary table, and the coding is more complicated.  My guess is that you have other things to worry about, so go with an approximation and note it as a place for future optimization.